# keep autoplay mp4 video inline on Safari iPhone? (not full screen)

Tags: iphone, mp4

On my website I have an embedded mp4 video which is supposed to autoplay once it loads.  This works except on iPhone Safari, where once the video loads, it goes fullscreen and obscures the rest of the site until it finishes playing, then it shrinks back to show the site again.

Is there any way to make the video play within the same screen rectangle it uses on desktop and iPad -- the one specified by my HTML -- and NOT have it go fullscreen?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 1):

No,video's played in mobile safari on the iPhone will always go fullscreen.

Comment: whoa that is not what I expected -- you can't use video as part of a specific web page design?  that is disappointing.

Comment: @rckoenes is right. THe only way to do that is have a native app.

Comment: Well -- is there any way in Javascript or HTML to detect iphone only, so I can throw up an image instead?  For other platforms I'd want to run the video inline.

Comment: The Javascript version mentioned here successfully detects iPhone for me: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone